# How to handle ember checkbox binding

Tags: ember.js

I am new with ember and I have a question about checkbox binding.

Here is my js && hbs :

```js
 CompletedToday(id){
          var today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
           this.get('DS').findRecord('menu',id).then((recs) => {
              recs.get('completedDates').pushObject(today);
              recs.save();
            });
      },
```

```html
{{#each menu}}


{{input type="checkbox" checked=this.checkCompleteToday click=(action "CompletedToday" menu.id)}}


{{/each}}
```

Menu is a model has a attribute called Completed date, which is a array contains a list of dates(YYYY-MM-DD), there should be a constructor function to check if it’s completed TODAY, if it is completed, make the checkbox of that menu as checked. If not, user can check the specific checkbox I don’t know how to handle this actually, do i need to create another attribute for menu?

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Please use formatting tools to properly edit and format your question.Codes within sentences are to be formatted as `code` 
Very Important words to be **bold** , lesser important onces *Italic*
Also use lists if necessary

Comment: Yes, this is the first time i post a question, i will modify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need a computed property that returns true or false if TODAY is in the model.

you should create in your component a computed property like:

```
checked = computed('model', function() {
    // pseudocode bellow
    return (TODAY in array)
})
```

Now, if it is unchecked (TODAY not in array), you should be able to insert in array.
In you hbs:

```
{{input type="checkbox" checked=checked click=(action "CompletedToday" menu.id)}}
```

(you shouldn't use "this" to reference the property)

If "CompletedToday" is in your component actions, it should work.
I hope this helps